# Reading chars from a stream of ByteArrays where boundary alignment may be imperfect

Tags: java, nio

I'm working with asynchronous IO on the JVM, wherein I'm occasionally handed a byte array from an incoming socket. Concatenated, these byte arrays form a stream which my overall goal is to split into strings by instance of a given character, be it newline, NUL, or something more esoteric.

I do not have any guarantee that the boundaries of these consecutive byte arrays are not part of the way through a multi-byte character.

Reading through the documentation for [java.nio.CharBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html), I don't see any explicit semantics given as to how trailing partial multibyte characters are handled.

Given a series of [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)s, what's the best way to get (complete) characters out of them, understanding that a character may span the gap between two sequencial ByteBuffers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CharsetDecoder`:

```
final Charset charset = ...
final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder()
    .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
```

I do have this problem in one of my projects, and [here](https://github.com/fge/largetext/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/largetext/load/TextDecoder.java#L236) is how I deal with it.

Note line 258: if the result is a malformed input sequence then it *may* be an incomplete read; in that case, I set the last good offset to the last decoded byte, and start again from that offset.

If, on the next read, I fail to read again *and* the *byte* offset is the same, then this is a permanent failure (line 215).

Your case is a little different however since you cannot "backtrack"; you'd need to fill a new `ByteBuffer` with the rest of the previous buffer and the new one and start from there (allocate for `oldBuf.remaining() + bufsize` and `.put()` from `oldBuf` into the new buffer). In my case, my backend is a file, so I can `.map()` from wherever I want.

So, basically:

- if you have an unmappable character, this is a permanent failure (your encoding just cannot handle your byte sequence);
- if you have read the full byte sequence successfully, your `CharBuffer` will have `buf.position()` characters in it;
- if you have a malformed input, it *may* mean that you have an incomplete byte sequence (for instance, using UTF-8, you have one byte out of a three byte sequence), but you need to confirm that with the next iteration.

Feel free to salvage any code you deem necessary! It's free ;)

---

FINAL NOTE, since I believe this is important: `String`'s `.getBytes(*)` methods and constructors from byte arrays have a default `CodingErrorAction` of `REPLACE`!